# Why the _source of the index I created by default is disabled in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Why the _source of the index I created by default is disabled in elasticsearch
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrBwL.png)

I did not use any templates，No matter how the index is created, _source is disabled.
My cluster may have insufficient disks before, but after my cleaning, the disk usage rate is within 20%

this is my index detail info

```json
{
  "test" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "_source" : {
        "enabled" : false
      },
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "Exception" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "log" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1636705210909",
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "8BRNRGnQSyOJzqMOHLXjHw",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7030099"
        },
        "provided_name" : "test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more context than that... How are you indexing data (adhoc app, Filebeat, Logstash, ...)? Do you have index templates installed with specific mappings?

Comment: I did not use any templates，No matter how the index is created, _source is disabled..

Comment: I created an index in kibana through rest api, and the _source of this index is still disabled

Comment: My cluster may have insufficient disks before, but after my cleaning, the disk usage rate is within 20%

Comment: What do you get when running `GET your-index-name` in Dev Tools? Please update your question with the response you get

Comment: Can you also provide the output you get from `GET _template`? 99.9% sure that there's an index templates kicking in when you create your index

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have modified the content, I make sure that this index does not use a template，I created this index arbitrarily

Comment: You are right, I see a template index_patterns is *, and _source is disabled